# how to prevent images from routing in angularjs ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i am having a problem loading an image from my directory.

My App is based on ui-router but now everytime i try to load my image I don’t get the image. I get an empty site.

path to image should be `http://localhost/client/style/images/profile.png`

can you tell me how to prevent the routing for images?

Comment: ui router has nothing to do with image. Images gets loaded by absolute path of location on server. It is the server who finds the image by path and serves. i thing the problem is somewhere else. First Check if image is present!

Comment: If your web server sends "an empty site" rather than the expected image, that has nothing to do with ui-router. It has to do with your web server.

Comment: thanks you were right.. i did not understand meteor correctly sorry for this.